# I have created a CNN model and now i want to draw its architecture diagram can anyone help me with that

Tags: deep-learning, cnn

following is my architecture:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=8, kernel_size=2, activation="relu", input_shape=(9, 1)))

# CNN Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))

# Flatten layer
model.add(Flatten())

# Fully connected Layer
model.add(Dense(16, activation="relu"))

# Decision Layer
model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
```

this is what i got from the code:
[image]

but i want architecture like this:
[image]

i dont know how many layers should i add can any one help me with this thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to use a graphical tool and create the diagram from scratch. I am not aware of a tool that can directly generate it from code. Bur your CNN is rather simple so it should be easily doable.

For instance :

https://alexlenail.me/NN-SVG/LeNet.html

https://github.com/HarisIqbal88/PlotNeuralNet